# Laravel access directly to json array in blade without using foreach statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in this result:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#251 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#246 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => ProductCategories {#247 ▼
        ...
        #attributes: array:6 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "category_name" => "test"
          "lang" => "fa"
          "images" => "{"images":{"original":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/1512736029.jpeg","300":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1512736029.jpeg","600":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/600_1512736029.jpeg","900":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/900_1512736029.jpeg"},"thumbnail":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1512736029.jpeg"} ◀"
          "created_at" => "2017-12-08 10:47:56"
          "updated_at" => "2017-12-08 12:27:10"
        ]
        #original: array:6 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "category_name" => "test test"
          "lang" => "fa"
          "images" => "{"images":{"original":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/1512736029.jpeg","300":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1512736029.jpeg","600":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/600_1512736029.jpeg","900":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/900_1512736029.jpeg"},"thumbnail":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1512736029.jpeg"} ◀"
          "created_at" => "2017-12-08 10:47:56"
          "updated_at" => "2017-12-08 12:27:10"
        ]
        ...
      }
      1 => ProductCategories {#248 ▶}
    ]
  }
```

which i get from this query:

```
$categories = ProductCategories::paginate(10);
dd($categories);
```

i'm trying to access to `"images"` column data such as `thumbnail` and `300` or etc, when i use `foreach` this data and show that on `table` i can't access to them, for example:

```
{{$categories->images->thumbnail}}
```

but i get `Undefined property` error and i can't show that

Comment: Do you need the pagination?

Comment: @Chamara Abeysekara no. i dont have any problem for paginate data, my problem is access directly to json data into `images` such as `thumbnail`

Comment: You will get `Undefined property` error if any one link is not present in your database. For eg- `catagory_id` 1,2,4 is present in related table but `category_id` 3 is not present in related table.

Comment: Can you do something like `ProductCategories::get()->pluck('images')` and `{{json_encode($categories)}}` ??

Answer (score 1):

How about you just **cast** that field to an array ...

```
class ProductCategories ...
{
    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array',
    ];

    ...
 }


 @foreach ($categories as $category)
     {{ $category->images['thumb'] }}
 @endforeach
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Mutators - Array and Json Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Comment: by default i'm using `$casts` in Model. my problem is access to json array without using `foreach` into `datatables` to show only `thumbnail` column

Comment: its a COLLECTION, how do you think you are going to get a **single** 'thumb' nail from an 'image' inside the collection (which are many) without asking for a single element from the collection or iterating it ...  `$categories` contains many ... `$categories->images` .. what would that even imply .. which 'category' do you want the `images` from ... are you getting it yet?

Comment: without using `foreach` i can access to `thumbnail` by this code `{{$categories[0]->images['thumbnail']}}`

Comment: "without asking for a single element from the collection or iterating it" ... you can't  (as your comment is getting a single element).. that was the point .. .its all the same you have to access an element of the collection first .. then you can get to that information .. its all the same

Comment: could you help me on this topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47717191/1830228 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$categories` is a Collection, so you need to get each individual object to get its data. For this you'll need to use a foreach.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->images }}
@endforeach
```

And to have access to `thumbnail` you'll need to decode the json string that you have in `images`. For that, you can use `json_decode($category->images)` function. This will return an array with `thumbnail` as key.

Comment: yes i know thats collection, in `table` as data pagination i cant use foreach and show add data of collection, i want to access to only `thumbnail` not all data

Comment: Since it's a JSON string, you will probably have to decode each one of it. I don't know if there is a direct way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it right, you should keep image related data in a separate table and use a relationship between category and image:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

But since you're keeping images data as JSON string, the first thing you want to do is to [cast it to array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting). Add this to the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'images' => 'array',
];
```

Then in Blade view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->images['thumbnail'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: could you help me on this topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47717191/1830228 Thanks in advance