# Laravel implementing belongsTo one product for one or some category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

in my database i have `product_category` and `products` that one `product` maybe belongs to one or some category in `product_category` table, now my question is: when user on submitting product with one or some category how can i save that on database to have for example one category have one or some product?

in view i have multiple select as:

```
{{ Form::select('categories[]', $productCategories, null, array('class' => 'multiselect-success multiselect_selected','multiple'=>'multiple')) }}
```

`products` model:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];

    public function productCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategories::class);
    }
}
```

`productCategories` model:

```
class ProductCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_categories';
    protected $guarded =['id'];
    protected $casts=[
        'images'=>'array'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Products::class);
    }
}
```

and `store` function into `controller`:

```
public function store(RequestProducts $request)
{
    try {
        $data = Products::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'product_code' => $request->product_code,
            'weight' => $request->weight
            /* MY PROBLEM IS HERE */
            'category_id' => $request->categories
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        ...
    }

    return redirect(route('manageProductCategories.index'));
}
```

in html view `categories` is an array and how can i implementing that?

**UPDATE**

after update code with `createMany` i get this error:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `lang`, `amount`, `product_code`, `weight`, `images`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (eqweqwe, fa, 45,000, asd, asdasd, '', 2017-12-09 04:45:44, 2017-12-09 04:45:44))
```

migration files:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->string('lang', 2);
        $table->text('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('amount');
        $table->string('product_code');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('lang', 2);
        $table->text('images');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a many-to-many relationship between a product and a category with an intermediary table.

Comment: have a look at : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @ab_in i dont have any problem on many-to-many but i think ths implementation is one-to-many

Comment: So you creating product successfully and now you need to create categories and attach it to your new product?

Comment: yes. attaching one post to one or some categories

Comment: Are you sure that category can have only one product?

Comment: one category can have one or some product. minimum such as 1 and maximum for example 100

Comment: in you `products` table which datatype is used to save `category_id`?

Comment: Your products table will only able to save a single category for a product and you are trying to save more than one category to one product.

Comment: @ab_in then how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question and comments, I understand the following.

Many products may have the category "category_1" and "product_1" may belongs to many categories.

To implement this you have to use "Many To Many" relationship.
I have updated your code, this might help you.

**Migrations:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->string('lang', 2);
        $table->text('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('amount');
        $table->string('product_code');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('lang', 2);
        $table->text('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products_product_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('product_category_id');
    });
}
```

**Models**

products model:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];

    public function productCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategories::class,'products_product_category');
    }
}
```

productCategories model:

```
class ProductCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_categories';
    protected $guarded =['id'];
    protected $casts=[
        'images'=>'array'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class, 'products_product_category');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(RequestProducts $request)
{
    try {
        $data = Products::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'product_code' => $request->product_code,
            'weight' => $request->weight
        ]);
        $data->productCategories()->sync($request->categories);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        ...
    }

    return redirect(route('manageProductCategories.index'));
}
```

Hope it will helps..

Comment: it seems you have right. please let me to check that

Comment: where is foreign keys on `products_product_category` file?

Comment: laravel automatically assigns forign key constraints..
`$table->integer('product_id');//foriegnkey for product table
$table->integer('product_category_id'); // foriegnkey for product_categories table`

Comment: refer laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for more info.